# How to reverse a string without changing the position of the words

Tags: java

My target is to reverse the string without changing the postion of the words, I want to print `"tesT eht tcudorp"`

```
public class roughWork {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Test the product";
        String arr[] = str.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = arr[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use something like `new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString()`

Comment: What's your question? What's the problem with your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're asking it to print the whole string repeatedly in this line: `System.out.print(arr[j]+" ");`. Changing that to print only an individual character will fix it:

```
public class roughWork {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String str= "Test the product";
      String arr[]=str.split(" ");
      for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
      {

          for(int j=arr[i].length()-1;j>=0;j--)
          {   
          System.out.print(arr[i].charAt(j));
          }
          System.out.print(" ");
      }
   }
}
```

The second print adds the space between each words after it has output all that words characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there just use charAt and print `arr[i].charAt(j)`

```
 String str = "Test the product";
 String arr[] = str.split(" ");
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    for (int j = arr[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(arr[i].charAt(j));
    }
    System.out.print(" ");
 }
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/E5vdur)

Answer (score -2):

```
class reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello India";
        String[] ch = s.split(" ");
        for (String chr : ch) {
            String rev = "";
            for (int i = chr.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                rev = rev + chr.charAt(i);
            }
            System.out.print(rev + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.